# Kestrel HTTPS BadHttpRequestException

Tags: https, kestrel

Over HTTP and inside of Visual Studio it is working fine. However, when I attempt to hit the endpoint over HTTPS I'm seeing this error and I'm not entirely sure how to figure out the problem:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
  Connection id "0HL36O0ESIPBQ" bad request data: "Invalid request line: <0x16><0x03><0x01><0x00><0x83><0x01><0x00><0x00><0x7F><0x03><0x01>X<0xC1><0x07><0xDC><0x9E>~Y<0x05><0x13><0xC1><0xF4>^J<0xCF><0xAB><0x11><0xC3>R[<0x87><0x1D>..."Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request line: <0x16><0x03><0x01><0x00><0x83><0x01><0x00><0x00><0x7F><0x03><0x01>X<0xC1><0x07><0xDC><0x9E>~Y<0x05><0x13><0xC1><0xF4>^J<0xCF><0xAB><0x11><0xC3>R[<0x87><0x1D>
```

Fiddler gives me this:

```
System.IO.IOException The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

My gut tells me this has to do with moving from dotnet core 1.0.1 to 1.1.0. This was all working fine before that point, but it is equally likely I screwed something else up and I'm just not sure what! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I'll answer my own question. It turns out I just needed to add .UseHttps to my WebHostBuilder in program.cs:

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.AddServerHeader = false;
    options.UseHttps("MyPfx", "MyPassword");
})
```

I guess I'm a little confused how this was working previously without this but hey, it works now!

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to Paul's hint in the form of an answer.

The .UseHttps class is in the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" module, which can be added by searching for "usehttps" in the Package Manager UI or by adding it to your project.json file. Note that at the time of this writing, version 1.1.1 is now available for ASP.NET Core, so be sure to choose the version you need.

Not sure it will solve my problem, but perhaps it will solve the problem of someone else that reads this.